# Simplifying calculation of arrays with Ramda

Tags: ramda.js

I would like to calculate the three arrays like this.

```
const Data =  {
   x : [2,4,6],
   y : [10,10,10],
   z : [5,5,5]
}

const XtimesYplusZ = zipWith (add, (zipWith (multiply, Data.x, Data.y)), Data.z)
console.log(XtimesYplusZ);//[25,45,65]
```

This code works ok, but not very good in terms of readability.
So, now I created calculation patterns that could be applied later on:

```
const calc1 =  ({x, y, z}) => x * y + z
console.log(calc1(Data)); //ERROR
```

This is not working. I have many different patterns such as `({x, y, z}) => x / y - z`, `({x, y, z}) => (x + y) * z` and so on. What is the standard calculation method for arrays something like this?

[REPL](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.27.0#?const%20Data%20%3D%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20x%20%3A%20%5B2%2C4%2C6%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20y%20%3A%20%5B10%2C10%2C10%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20z%20%3A%20%5B5%2C5%2C5%5D%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20XtimesYplusZ%20%3D%20zipWith%20%28add%2C%20%28zipWith%20%28multiply%2C%20Data.x%2C%20Data.y%29%29%2C%20Data.z%29%0Aconsole.log%28XtimesYplusZ%29%3B%2F%2FWorks%20but%20not%20ideal.%0A%0Aconst%20calc1%20%3D%20%20%28%7Bx%2C%20y%2C%20z%7D%29%20%3D%3E%20x%2Ay%2Bz%0Aconsole.log%28calc1%28Data%29%29%3B%20%2F%2FERROR%0A)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example:

```
const calc1 =  ({x, y, z}) => x * y + z
console.log(calc1(Data)); //ERROR
```

You are trying to add and multiply arrays, and not the arrays' items.

Using R.zipWith won't work as well, since it requires actual arrays, and is limited to zipping 2 arrays at a time.

An easier solution would be to get the sub-arrays using R.props, transpose them (`[[2, 10, 5], [4, 10, 5]]...`), and then map and combine the values using your `calc` function (I've replace the object destructuring with array destructuring):

```js
const { pipe, props, transpose, map } = R

const calc = ([x, y, z]) => x * y + z

const fn = pipe(props(['x', 'y', 'z']), transpose, map(calc))

const Data =  {
   x : [2,4,6],
   y : [10,10,10],
   z : [5,5,5]
}

const XtimesYplusZ = fn(Data)

console.log(XtimesYplusZ) // [25,45,65]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-rZHvUXcc1zWKsxm7rJ8lVQuIr1oOmm7cShlvpV0gWf0RvbcJN6x96al/Rp2L2BI4a4ZkT2/YfVe/8YvB2UHzQw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

This example show Scott's suggestion of extracting out the combination of R.transpose, and R.map to create a `zipAllWith` function:

```js
const { curry, map, apply, transpose, pipe, props } = R

const zipAllWith = curry((fn, xss) => map(apply(fn), transpose(xss)));

const fn = pipe(props(['x', 'y', 'z']), zipAllWith((x, y, z) => x * y + z))

const Data =  {
   x : [2,4,6],
   y : [10,10,10],
   z : [5,5,5]
}

const XtimesYplusZ = fn(Data)

console.log(XtimesYplusZ) // [25,45,65]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-rZHvUXcc1zWKsxm7rJ8lVQuIr1oOmm7cShlvpV0gWf0RvbcJN6x96al/Rp2L2BI4a4ZkT2/YfVe/8YvB2UHzQw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Nice.  I've done several implementations of `zipAll[With]`, but don't think I've ever thought to use `transpose`.  That's an elegant solution.  I would prefer to expose it as a helper function, `const zipAllWith = (fn) => (xss) => map (apply (fn), transpose (xss));
pipe (props (['x', 'y', 'z']), zipAllWith ((x, y, z) => x * y + z)) (Data) //=> [25, 45, 65]`

Comment: I am in love with Ramda. This solution makes my code a lot simpler. Thank you so much.